# How to scrape a website with many sibling elements, of which the number of them is uncertain? BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, siblings

I want to scrape video game's release information. The structure of all relevant tags is shown in this picture (the specific case is from this link: https://www.mobygames.com/game/ps2/007-nightfire/release-info).

[A screen shot from the above website link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jk8za.png)

What I want to do is to scrape all release information and store it in a dataframe.

The code I have so far is as following. However, I don't think how to finish the code as many things are undetermined. Is there a way to write such web scraper in a for-loop?

Here is my current code

```
def get_releases(url):
    response = requests.get(url + '/release-info', headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"})
    assert response.status_code == 200, "Problem with url request! %s throws %s" % (
        url,
        response.status_code,
    ) 
    page = response.text
    release_soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    return release_soup


def get_releases_info(release_soup):
    game_releases_info = defaultdict()
    
    title = release_soup.find('h1').findNext('a').text
    game_releases_info['title'] = title
    
    console = release_soup.find('h2').text
    game_releases_info['console'] = console
    
    release_list = release_soup.find('h2').findNextSiblings('div')
    num_cells = len(release_list)
    for tag in release_list:
        if tag.attrs == {'class': ['floatholder']}:
            field = tag.div.text.lower()
            value = tag.a.text
            game_releases_info[field] = value
        else: # not finishing...
```

Comment: Don't scrape MobyGames, as it makes the site slower for other users and you risk getting blocked. Request an API key to retrieve all this data you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get siblings elements, you can follow the next example. So far so good,getting the desired output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0"}
url = requests.get("https://www.mobygames.com/game/ps2/007-nightfire/release-info",headers=headers)
#print(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.text,'lxml')
data = []
for d in soup.select('div.floatholder'): 
    p=list(d.stripped_strings)
    data2.append({p[0]:''.join(p[1:])})

final_data = {
    'title':soup.select_one('.niceHeaderTitle > a').get_text(strip=True),
    'console':soup.find('h2').text, 'release':data
    }

print(final_data)
```

**Output:**

```
{'title': '007: Nightfire', 'console': 'PlayStation 2', 'release': [{'Published by': 'Electronic Arts, Inc.'}, {'Developed by': 'Eurocom Developments Ltd,Savage Entertainment, LLC'}, {'Publishing label': 'EA Games'}, {'Cutscenes by': '1K|Studios,Dan Krech Productions, Inc.,Mondo Media, Inc.'}, {'Additional Sound by': 'Soundelux Design Music Group,SPG Studios'}, {'Voice Recording by': 'Open Door Productions'}, {'Testing by': 'EA Tiburon'}, {'Licensed by': 'Danjaq, LLC,United Artists Corporation'}, {'Countries': 'United States,Canada'}, {'Release Date': 'Nov 19, 2002'}, {'UPC-A': '0\xa014633\xa014592\xa02'}, {'Sony PN': 'SLUS-20579'}, {'Published by': 
'Electronic Arts, Inc.'}, {'Developed by': 'Eurocom Developments Ltd,Savage Entertainment, LLC'}, {'Publishing label': 'EA Games'}, {'Distributed by': 'Electronic Arts France'}, {'Cutscenes by': '1K|Studios,Dan Krech Productions, Inc.,Mondo Media, Inc.'}, {'Additional Sound by': 'Soundelux Design Music Group,SPG Studios'}, {'Testing by': 'EA Tiburon'}, {'Country': 'France'}, {'Release Date': 'Nov 28, 2002'}, {'EAN-13': '5\xa0030931\xa0032394'}, {'Published by': 'Electronic Arts, Inc.'}, {'Developed by': 'Eurocom Developments Ltd,Savage Entertainment, LLC'}, 
{'Publishing label': 'EA Games'}, {'Localized by': 'Effective Media GmbH'}, {'Cutscenes by': '1K|Studios,Dan Krech Productions, Inc.,Mondo Media, Inc.'}, {'Additional Sound by': 'Soundelux Design Music Group,SPG Studios'}, {'Voice Recording by': 'Open Door Productions'}, {'Testing 
by': 'EA Tiburon'}, {'Licensed by': 'Danjaq, LLC,United Artists Corporation'}, {'Country': 'United Kingdom'}, {'Release Date': 'Nov 29, 2002'}, {'EAN-13': '5\xa0030930\xa0032395'}, {'Sony 
PN': 'SLES-51258'}, {'Published by': 'Electronic Arts, Inc.'}, {'Developed by': 'Eurocom Developments Ltd,Savage Entertainment, LLC'}, {'Publishing label': 'EA Games'}, {'Distributed by': 
'Electronic Arts Deutschland GmbH'}, {'Cutscenes by': '1K|Studios,Dan Krech Productions, Inc.,Mondo Media, Inc.'}, {'Additional Sound by': 'Soundelux Design Music Group,SPG Studios'}, {'Testing by': 'EA Tiburon'}, {'Country': 'Germany'}, {'Release Date': 'Nov 29, 2002'}, {'EAN-13': '5\xa0030932\xa0032393'}, {'Sony PN': 'SLES-51260'}, {'Published by': 'Electronic Arts, Inc.'}, {'Developed by': 'Eurocom Developments Ltd,Savage Entertainment, LLC'}, {'Publishing label': 'EA Games'}, {'Cutscenes by': '1K|Studios,Dan Krech Productions, Inc.,Mondo Media, Inc.'}, {'Additional Sound by': 'Soundelux Design Music Group,SPG Studios'}, {'Testing by': 'EA Tiburon'}, {'Country': 'Japan'}, {'Release Date': 'Jan 30, 2003'}, {'EAN-13': '4\xa0938833\xa0005830'}, {'Sony PN': 'SLPS-25203'}, {'Country': 'Japan'}, {'Release Date': 'Feb 11, 2004'}, {'Comments': 'EA Best Hits release'}, {'EAN-13': '4\xa0938833\xa0006257'}, {'Sony PN': 'SLPM-65538'}]}
```

Comment: good solution may you do not need a second `data` variable if you define the list already in your dict you could append directly to it  ->  `data = {
    'title':soup.select_one('.niceHeaderTitle > a').get_text(strip=True),
    'console':soup.find('h2').text,
    'releases':[]
    }`

Comment: Thanks for both of you! The answer is very helpful. One question: why we can also use ' .niceHeaderTitle' rather than 'h1' to find certain element? (very new to web scraping... cannot find clear answer about this question).

Comment: @Xiaowei Zhang h1 will also work here but with all stuffs. .niceHeaderTitle'  is class attribute value of h1 tag which is more flexible in case of many h1.   .niceHeaderTitle' is css selector that I use